# Flutter: How to get data show DrawerWidget as per the user or admin which is stored in sharedPreference?

Tags: flutter, widget, sharedpreferences, flutter-layout, navigation-drawer

I am trying to show the drawer according to user and I have stored user type in shared Preference. But when I open drawer I could not get data from sharedPreferences before loading drawer?

```
        widget.userType == 'admin'
            ? ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.receipt),
                title: Text("User Record"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => UserRecord()),
                    (Route<dynamic> route) => route is UserRecord,
                  );
                },
              )
            : Container(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a way to do so. But I am not sure its correct way to do it or not.
I used futureBuilder and passed future as:

```
pref.getString('userType');
```